# Why can I use opengl 4 function in opengl 3 environment

Tags: opengl

I'am making a app running on ubuntu with freeglut. I used `glutInitContextVersion(3, 3)` and when I call `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`, the function returns `3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.3.2`. But I can use `glTexStorage2D` function and the function operates well. Opengl Reference page tells that the function is compatible with `opengl 4.2` or higher version. Why can I use this function? I use Intel Ivy Bridge i3 cpu and Intel GPU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If context initialization succeeds, it only means the version you ended up with is compatible with the version you requested. It doesn't prevent a higher version from being used behind the scenes. As for the version string, it's likely just lying to you for compatibility reasons, since you requested an older context version.

Comment: FYI: the version string is not lying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that function probably because your implementation implements ARB_texture_storage. See, ARB_texture_storage's functions don't end in `ARB`. It defines the exact same functions that OpenGL 4.2 does, with the exact same behavior.

This allows a 3.3 implementation to implement *select features* from higher versions, but without having you use different functions. There's no point in having `glTexStorageARB` be a different function from `glTexStorage`, since they do the same thing.

These kinds of extensions are called "backwards-compatibility extensions" or "[core extensions](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Extension)".